# How do I Create a CSV file in C#

Tags: c#, file, csv, filesystems

I am new to file system. I need to create a simple csv file and need to write string in the file and read it back.

I am getting some unicode value in the file that got created. How do i write string value by creating csv and reading back from it.

So far I have wrote this. Need little hele here.

Below is my code.

```
        static void Main()
    {
        string folderName = @"D:\Data";
        string pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(folderName, "SubFolder");
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString);
        string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName();
        pathString = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathString, fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("Path to my file: {0}\n", pathString);

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(pathString))
        {
            using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(pathString))
            {
                {
                    byte a = 1;
                    fs.WriteByte(a);
                }
            }
        }

        // Read and display the data from your file.
        try
        {
            byte[] readBuffer = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(pathString);
            foreach (byte b in readBuffer)
            {
                Console.Write(b + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you researched this at all?  This is a simple task that most likely has many, many examples out there.

Comment: And what exactly is the question?

Comment: @rory.ap I tried but i was getting unwanted values in the file that gets created

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write a csv file using streamwriter. Your file will be located in bin/Debug (if running debug mode and not stating otherwise).

```
 var filepath = "your_path.csv";
 using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(filepath,
 FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
 {
     writer.WriteLine("sep=,");
     writer.WriteLine("Hello, Goodbye");
 }
```

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help.

Comment: This is how i was trying to write the striing char a = 'a';                        fs.Write(a[], 1, 1); Now I get the point

Answer (score 3):

You can create a specific file type using the appropriate extension, in this case ".csv".
Below is a quick example using the filepath and a random string.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace CSVExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string data = "Col1, Col2, Col2";
            string filePath = @"File.csv";
            File.WriteAllText(filePath, data);
            string dataFromRead = File.ReadAllText(filePath);
            Console.WriteLine(dataFromRead);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]